# Null check operator used on null value (but only in Android Studio)

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a singed bundle from Flutter code in Android Studio, but am getting the error

```
Null check operator used on null value
```

I understand the error but cannot seem to debug it.  Furthermore, when I run the app in VSCode on an Android emulator it does not throw error.  The stacktrace is

```
#0      ClosureIdMetadataRepository.getClosureId (package:vm/metadata/closure_id.dart:35)
#1      AnnotateKernel._convertType (package:vm/transformations/type_flow/transformer.dart:380)
#2      AnnotateKernel._setInferredArgType (package:vm/transformations/type_flow/transformer.dart:425)
#3      AnnotateKernel._annotateMember (package:vm/transformations/type_flow/transformer.dart:518)
#4      AnnotateKernel.visitProcedure (package:vm/transformations/type_flow/transformer.dart:596)
#5      Procedure.accept (package:kernel/ast.dart:3198)
#6      visitList (package:kernel/ast.dart:14670)
#7      Class.visitChildren (package:kernel/ast.dart:1483)
#8      DartScopeBuilder.defaultTreeNode (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/expression_compiler.dart:117)
#9      VisitorDefault.defaultTreeNode (package:kernel/visitor.dart:1521)
#10     TreeVisitorDefault.defaultExpression (package:kernel/visitor.dart:618)
#11     Class.accept (package:kernel/ast.dart:1445)
#12     visitList (package:kernel/ast.dart:14670)
#13     Library.visitChildren (package:kernel/ast.dart:593)
#14     DartScopeBuilder.defaultTreeNode (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/expression_compiler.dart:117)
#15     VisitorDefault.defaultTreeNode (package:kernel/visitor.dart:1521)
#16     TreeVisitorDefault.defaultExpression (package:kernel/visitor.dart:618)
#17     Library.accept (package:kernel/ast.dart:582)
#18     visitList (package:kernel/ast.dart:14670)
#19     Component.visitChildren (package:kernel/ast.dart:14493)
#20     RecursiveVisitor.defaultNode (package:kernel/visitor.dart:1727)
#21     VisitorDefault.defaultTreeNode (package:kernel/visitor.dart:1521)
#22     TreeVisitorDefaultMixin.visitComponent (package:kernel/visitor.dart:600)
#23     AnnotateKernel.visitComponent (package:vm/transformations/type_flow/transformer.dart:713)
#24     transformComponent (package:vm/transformations/type_flow/transformer.dart:148)
#25     runGlobalTransformations (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:574)
#26     compileToKernel (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:478)
<asynchronous suspension>
#27     FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:637)
<asynchronous suspension>
#28     starter (package:frontend_server/starter.dart:102)
<asynchronous suspension>
#29     main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I recently upgraded flutter also.

Comment: It would help to see the line of code that's causing this issue. Could you copy & paste `frontend_server.dart`, line 13?

Comment: @nate-thegrate I'm looking for it now, can't seem to find it

Comment: I'm just going to recreate the entire flutter project, i changed too many thigns too quickly

Comment: This error is due to the flutter upgrade. If you're using `!` in code, must not be `null`

Comment: @ankushlokhande Thanks, I understand the error, I'm just having trouble finding it.  Why would it run in debug but not build correctly for release?  I'd expect such an error would be caught when debugging.

Comment: Also I can build in Android Studio, I'm only having trouble generating a signed bundle.

Comment: Just for be sure, have you already tried to do a  `flutter clean` and then  `flutter pub get ` ?

Comment: @Phoenix multiple times, I think what has happened is that I accidentally deleted my `.android` folder and now I have to request a new upload key.  Waiting for approval now, but if this is the reason then this error is bizarre